# Writing a function that counts how many times each number is randomly generated

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering how I can write a function that generates iters random numbers in the range 0 through max - 1 and returns an array counts in which the the element counts[i] is the number of times that value i was generated. The following is what I've written so far.

```
  public static int[] randomExperiment(int max, int iters)
  {
      Random randomGenerator = new Random();
      for(int i = 0; i < iters; i += 1)
      {
          int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(max - 1);
      }
      int[] counts = new int [iters];

  }
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that very clear. How do I count how many of each value has been randomly generated?

Comment: Just create a new array `int[] counter = new int[max]` and inside the loop do something like `counter[randomInt]++`.

Comment: I think you'd want to have `nextInt(max)`, by the way. It will give you numbers from `0` to `max-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int[] randomExperiment(int max, int iters)
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int[] counts = new int [max];
    for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(max);
        counts[randomInt]++;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Kudos to Gendame and Titus